# Detect keyboard type changes in custom keyboard for iOS 8

Tags: objective-c, ios8, ios-app-extension, custom-keyboard

I'm currently creating an iOS 8 custom keyboard extension, and I'm looking for a way to determine when the users switch to another input, in order to change my layout.

For example, when a users selects a `UITextField` with type `UIKeyboardTypeEmailAddress` I intend to present a custom keyboard, and when the user selects another `UITextField` with type `UIKeyboardTypeDecimalPad`, I want to notice it, and update my keyboard's layout. How does one get notified when the keyboard type changes in order to update the keyboard layout?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can detect changes to the keyboard type in `textDidChange`. You need to get the `UITextDocumentProxy` then check the proxy's `keyboardType`. If it's a keyboard type you want to support, you can then present the appropriate UI. For example, this is how you would detect when the email keyboard should be displayed:

```
override func textDidChange(textInput: UITextInput) {
    // Called when the document context is changed - theme or keyboard type changes

    var proxy = self.textDocumentProxy as UITextDocumentProxy
    if proxy.keyboardType == UIKeyboardType.EmailAddress {
        //add code here to display email input keyboard
    }
}
```

Comment: it is not calling when the keyboard type is changing or when user press 123/ABC buttons